# Ubuntu Server 12.04: Bad archive mirror

Tags: 12.04, server

I get stucked when installing Ubuntu Server 12.04 on my laptop. When it comes to "Choose a mirror of the Ubuntu archive", I get 'bad archive mirror' error. I've tried many times with other options provided, but still got the error.

How to solve this? Can anyone help me?

p/s: Sorry I am quite newbie in Ubuntu. But familiar with Ubuntu Desktop.

Regards,

-Ismi

Comment: Here is the mirror list:` https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors` tried these ?

Comment: Also make sure you can access the files via http://localhost/ubuntu on the web server to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 1):

for anyone else that gets here - the 'bad archive mirror' error can be a problem from a nameserver not working!

If you get here, make sure you verify that the nameserver you set (if you're not using DHCP) works - you should be able to go to virtualconsole 2-3 and use ping to verify you can ping things first... then see that you can ping the dns server you're trying to use.

Changing the DNS server I was trying to use fixed this problem for me, after attempting to use a few different ubuntu versions since the errors in syslog were saying 'mirror does not have any suitable symlinks' or other errors that made it look like it just wasn't the right mirror.

Comment: I am NOT using internet to install Ubuntu Server. How to install then?