# MAAS - Choose a Mirror of the Ubuntu Archive: Bad archive mirror

Tags: juju, maas

I'm testing MAAS in a virtual network on Ubuntu Trusty LTS. 
I done the following steps:

1. Importing the boot images.
2. Creating 6 virt-nodes, and making their boot as PXE.
3. The nodes already added to the cluster controller automatically.
4. I finished editing the power type of the 6 nodes, to be virsh.
5. Commissioning the 6 nodes.
6. Finally when starting the 6 nodes, it continue to install Ubuntu on all the nodes, but it give me the following error message!

   ```
   [!!] Choose a mirror of the Ubuntu archive
   ------------------------------------------
   Bad archive mirror
   -------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

I tried to change it, but also the same error message

Any Suggestions??

Answer (score 1):

According to this related question and answer - https://askubuntu.com/a/437151/207309,
this might be due to a DNS issue. If you can double-check your MAAS cluster controller (in the MAAS web UI) is set to manage DNS and DHCP on the its network interfaces? You might need to also go into your MAAS settings page and add a backup DNS, like 8.8.8.8 and see if it helps?